# What is the performance efficient way to convert Eigen's Matrix to c array so that I can use gsl

Tags: c++, pointers, eigen, arrays

I use Eigen for most of my code but I would like to use Miser or Vegas monte-carlo integration from GSL. I need to convert Eigen's vectors to c arrays of `double`s
what would be the best way to do it?

```
Matrix<double,3,1> --> c_array []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked with Eigen before...

Usually, for simple access to the internal array data, like [mentioned by user janneb in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443102/convert-eigen-matrix-to-c-array), you just want to [invoke **data()**](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a4663159a1450fa89214b1ab71f7ef5bf):

```
Vector3d v;
// Operations to add values to the vector.
double *c_ptr = v.data();
```

If you wish to iterate the individual values to perform some operation, you want to iterate every **line (.row(index))** and **column (.col(index))**, depending on the matrix order that you want to lay down in the destination vector.

In your specific example, you need only iterate the rows:

```
Matrix<double,3,1> --> c_array []
```

You would want to call **.col(0)**. Should similar needs arise, [the specific documentation is always helpful!](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html)

So you would end up with something like (assuming you wish to use a three-line single-column matrix):

```
Vector3d v;
// Operations to add values to the vector.
for (int i=0; i<v.rows(); ++i)
  c_array[i] = v(i,0);
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: i was hoping for something without copying. but this would do for now

Comment: Check the top of the answer :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this for your game bot project? If so, are you going to make an open-source library? What language will it be interfaced in? C++?

Comment: Heh, not working on the game bot unfortunately. I'm using this for physical chemistry research to write a semiclassical propagator to simulate how atoms move.