# Using Eigen 3.3 in a CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, eigen3

Since Nov. 2016 it's possible to compile CUDA code which references Eigen3.3 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745481/4069571)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23804859/4069571) is not what I'm looking for and may now be "outdated" in the sense that there might now be an easier way, since the following is written in the [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.3#Experimental_CUDA_support)

> Starting from Eigen 3.3, it is now possible to use Eigen's objects and
>   algorithms within CUDA kernels. However, only a subset of features are
>   supported to make sure that no dynamic allocation is triggered within
>   a CUDA kernel.

See also [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCUDA.html). Unfortunately, I was not able to find any example of how this might look like.

### My Question

**Is it now possible to write a kernel such as the following**, which should simply calculate a bunch of dot products?

```
__global__ void cu_dot(Eigen::Vector3d *v1, Eigen::Vector3d *v2, double *out, size_t N)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(idx < N)
    {
        out[idx] = v1[idx].dot(v2[idx]);
    }
    return;
}
```

I can compile this, but it does not seem to work. When I try to copy the data to host, I get `illegal memory access`. Note that I originally store the Vector3d's as `std::vector and then respectively use

```
cudaMalloc((void **)&p_device_v1, sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d)*n);
cudaMemcpy(p_v1_device, v1.data(), sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d)*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I have set up an **MWE project** using CMake at https://github.com/GPMueller/eigen-cuda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the MWE project on github, you wrote:

```
double dot(std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> v1, std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> v2)
{   
    ...     
    // Dot product
    cu_dot<<<(n+1023)/1024, 1024>>>(v1.data(), v2.data(), dev_ret, n);
```

The `v1.data()` and `v2.data()` pointers are in the CPU memory. You need to use the pointers in the GPU memory, i.e.

```
// Dot product
cu_dot<<<(n+1023)/1024, 1024>>>(dev_v1, dev_v2, dev_ret, n);
```

The CPU vs GPU results are *not* identical, but that's an issue with the code, i.e. you didn't perform a reduction on the multiple dot products.

Comment: A very embarrassing mistake... The MWE is now fixed and working as intended.
Thanks!

Comment: @GMueller It happens to us all.