# Copy an Eigen vector to a C array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, eigen

How do I copy an Eigen vector `mesh` to a C array `r`?

```
double *r;
typedef Eigen::VectorXd RealVector;
Eigen::Map<RealVector>(r, 1, mesh.cols()) = mesh;
```

gives an assert from Eigen

```
DenseBase::resize() does not actually allow to resize.
```

The same message comes from either

```
Eigen::Map<RealVector>(r, mesh.cols()) = mesh;
```

or

```
Eigen::Map<RealVector>(r, mesh.cols(), 1) = mesh;
```

I need the values to be copied, not just mapped.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29865019/4342498) you need to allocate the space for `r` yourself.

Comment: I did allocate space for `r`; just didn't show that part in the code. But if I hadn't, I'd be getting a different error, such as an access violation.

Comment: What is the size of `mesh`? I.e. does it have exactly 1 row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not clarify, I'm speculating three possible errors you could have made:

- Either your `mesh` is actually a `VectorXd`, but then it will always have exactly one column, but potentially multiple rows, i.e., you need to write:

  ```
  Eigen::VectorXd::Map(r, mesh.rows()) = mesh;
  ```
- Or your `mesh` is a `RowVectorXd` (i.e., having one row and multiple columns). Then you need to write:

  ```
  Eigen::RowVectorXd::Map(r, mesh.cols()) = mesh;
  ```
- If `mesh` actually is a matrix, you need to decide how to map it to linear memory (i.e. row-major or column-major). This is also possible with `Map`:

  ```
  Eigen::MatrixXd::Map(r, mesh.rows(), mesh.cols()) = mesh;
  ```

Comment: Tnx for your detailed analysis. Here is what the debugger is showing for `mesh`: Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
-  Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1> > {m_storage m_rows=500 } } . It is indeed a VectorXd, but I had rows and cols switched. `Eigen::Map<RealVector>(r, mesh.rows()) = mesh` works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to copy anything actually.  You can access the raw data using the `.data()` member function.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd mesh = Eigen::VectorXd::Random(10);
  double * r = mesh.data();

  r[5] = 0; // writes to mesh directly
  assert(mesh(5) == 0);
}
```

If you want to copy the data to the pointer, you have to allocate memory, perform the copy and deallocate after use.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd mesh = Eigen::VectorXd::Random(10);
  double * r = new double[mesh.size()];

  std::copy(mesh.data(), mesh.data() + mesh.size(), r);
  assert(r[5] == mesh(5));

  delete[] r;
}
```

Comment: Tnx for the info. As I said in the original post, I needed a copy of the data in separate memory (which I had allocated, but not shown in my code). And, as chtz suggested, `Eigen::Map<RealVector>(r, mesh.rows()) = mesh` worked as I wanted.